# Create a local ESXi user through vCenter

Tags: vmware-esxi

The Users and Groups tab doesn't appear presumably because I'm connected through vCenter (ESXi 4.1).  Can you:

a) authenticate via AD integration to an ESXi host directly through vCLI or vSphere client directly to the host?  Doesn't appear like I can, but maybe I'm missing something.

b) any way to create an administrators user on an ESXi via vCenter/vSphere client?

Gyst of it is that I need to do updates, don't have root password (using `vihostupdate` via vCLI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the host selected in vCenter, click the **Configuration** tab, then click **Authentication Services**.  By default, you only have Local Authentication at the host level, but if you click Properties on this screen, it will bring up a window allowing you to enable Active Directory as an auth service and specify the domain to use.